# Where to put $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart')?

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing some major re-factoring on my app. I started how I suspect a lot of new Angular devs start by making one big main controller and putting everything in it. Over the past week or so I've been pulling a lot of stuff out into Services and separating controllers, but the one thing I'm not sure what to do with is the `$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart')`. It's not specific to any part of the view, it just sits on the page and waits for it to change. What's the best place to put this kind of line?

Comment: Surely that depends on what the method does in the event handler

Comment: It does a couple of things. It removes an event listener on the video element and it resets a `questionNumber` variable which is used by several parts of the application and resides in a kind of "state" service.

Comment: Can't you add a controller or two controllers that handles just those things? Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433568/is-it-good-to-have-main-controller-in-angular which has a "main" controller to just handle those application wide things

Comment: I could certainly just leave it in the `main` controller. I was just under the impression that it was "bad form". The purpose of this line is basically to just "reset" parts of the page. Maybe I'm just being too finicky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well because it's attached to `$rootScope` you can attach it anywhere (provided `$rootScope` is a dependency). You can think of `$rootScope` as a global service. However, in my case I like to put in in the `app.run()` function.